# ContextMenu не скрывается при выполнении команды

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, menu, task

Использую библиотеку Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification для отображения в трее иконки приложения:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="NotifyIcon"
                IconSource="/Resources/iconOn.ico"
                ToolTipText="{Binding Source={StaticResource Lang}, XPath=tt6}"
                DoubleClickCommand="{Binding DoubleMouseClick}"
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource SysTrayMenu}"
                PreviewTrayContextMenuOpen="NotifyIcon_OnPreviewTrayContextMenuOpen">
    <!-- self-assign a data context (could also be done programmatically) -->
    <tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
        <mpAutoUpdater:NotifyIconViewModel/>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
</tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

Контекстное меню лежит в ресурсах. Особо смотреть там не на что. Для контекстного меню установлено свойство StaysOpen="False". Для пункта меню установлено свойство StaysOpenOnClick="False". К пункту меню привязана команда:

```
public ICommand CheckUpdatesCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand
        {
            CommandAction = () =>
            {
                ModuleUpdate.CheckAndUpdateModule(true);
                Updater.CheckAndUpdateAll(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Реализация DelegateCommand взята прям из примера для библиотеки:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public Action CommandAction { get; set; }

    public Func<bool> CanExecuteFunc { get; set; }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        CommandAction();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecuteFunc == null || CanExecuteFunc();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}
```

Так вот - при нажатии на пункт в меню контекстное меню продолжает отображаться открытым, пока выполняется код в команде. Я уже пробовал выносить в другой поток вот так:

```
public ICommand CheckUpdatesCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand
        {
            CommandAction = () =>
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
                {
                    ModuleUpdate.CheckAndUpdateModule(true);
                    Updater.CheckAndUpdateAll(true);
                }));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Бесполезно.

Что самое интересное - меню остается висеть не как нормальное меню, а как визуальный артефакт на экране. Т.е. оно уже не активно и по нему не кликнуть.

Я пробовал и ставить значение IsOpen="False" перед выполнением команды - тоже не помогло.

Что еще можно попробовать?

**UPD:**
Добавляю gif'ку с отображением проблемы: при клике на пункт "Проверить обновления" работают методы, которые могут занять некоторое время (пару секунд). Они работают в основном потоке. И пока работа их не закончится - меню не исчезает. Вот это и нужно устранить

[image: Пример]

Comment: `Я уже пробовал выносить в другой поток вот так` - так это не вынос в другой поток, вы просто из UI потока вызываете UI поток.

Comment: @tym32167, я пробовал через Task.Run() - та же фигня

Comment: как именно пробовали? Ну, или, значит, смотрите, что ваши методы внутри делают, не стопают ли они UI поток.

Comment: @tym32167, так в том и вопрос, что меню должно исчезнуть до того, как начнутся методы из команды. А там уже все-равно - стопают они основной UI или нет.

Comment: `меню должно исчезнуть до того, как начнутся методы из команды` это почему?

Comment: @tym32167, потому что это приложение работает в трее и да - с основным потоком. Сам процесс выполнения методов никак не отображается пользователю (за исключением смены иконки) и поэтому по клику меню должно исчезать моментально и потом уже пускать методы. Сейчас сделаю gif'ку и приложу к вопросу

Comment: `по клику меню должно исчезать моментально и потом уже пускать методы` это ваши домыслы или почему вы так решили? Насколько я помню, контекстное меню не исчезнет ДО вызова команды

Comment: @tym32167, так в том-то и дело - меню исчезает только ПОСЛЕ выполнения команды

Comment: ну так оно так и должно работать же :)

Comment: в общем, запускайте вашу работу асинхронно или в параллельном потоке, чтобы не фризить основной UI поток, судя по гифке он у вас фризится, в этом и проблема

Comment: @tym32167, да ну? А если я там запускаю процесс с расчетами на пол часа, то я должен смотреть пол-часа на контекстное меню? Я понимаю, что нужно запускать работу в другом потоке, но у меня не получилось. Сейчас добавлю к вопросу как я пробовал

Comment: так и есть, если вы в команде запустите расчеты на полчаса в UI потоке, то прога зафризится на полчаса, это верно

Answer (score 0):

В общем получилось только вот так:

```
public ICommand CheckUpdatesCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand
        {
            CommandAction = async () =>
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(500);

                    void RunUpdaters()
                    {
                        ModuleUpdate.CheckAndUpdateModule(true);
                        Updater.CheckAndUpdateAll(true);
                    }

                    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(RunUpdaters));
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Только в таком случае меню у меня пропадает перед началом работы.

P.S. Методы **ModuleUpdate.CheckAndUpdateModule(true);** и **Updater.CheckAndUpdateAll(true);** должны работать в основном потоке, так как там происходит много обращений к главному UI